# OSB reporting, report multiple content. $body, $inbound, $outbound

Tags: xquery, soa, osb, oracle-service-bus

I am trying to put multiple values inside this content with this XQuery Expression Builder. I tried to use a string function like this`fn:concat($body, $inbound, $inbound)`, but this does not seems to keep the whole message.

[image: Reporting Properties: Content]

Is there any way that I can put all these variables in one report action? If this is possble then how should I read these values out after they are stored in the database(some key value structure would be perfect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I would try something like this:

```
<myroot>{$body, $inbound, $outbound}</myroot>
```

Or if you really need a string returned:

```
fn:serialize(<myroot>{$body, $inbound, $outbound}</myroot>)
```

Note, fn:serialize is only in OSB 12c+.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to form a xml with the content you want to show in your report:

```
<report>
   <body>{$body}</body>
   <inbound>{$inbound}</inbound>
   ...
</report>
```

the only requirement is that the output have to be an XML no matter the structure.

Comment: You are right, my problem was I did not put it into the XML tag, that's why it was not displaying correctly.